# Updating / Indexing auto generated 1 million pages after around two years

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I have auto generated 1 million page website. Pages are Something like https://www.comprsite.net/www/stackoverflow.com (Feel fee to remove the URL if it is against SE TOC).......

Now website is almost two years over. And I received around 5000 organic views per month.

There is no increase of traffic last 6 month... I mean traffic is almost same in last 6 month.

The questions I have.........

1. Even it has one million pages Google indexed only around 40,000 pages still. (Yes, I have submitted multiple site maps)

   Why Google not indexed other pages even after two years gone?
2. If I update (all pages will be updating), will Google notice that I have updated all pages? If not what can I do about it?
3. 5000 organic views per month is not enough to just cover the hosting fee. So I need to increase traffic little bit. Is there anything can I do to increase traffic which is not in the [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) ? I asked this question because I can't apply most of the points in above question because this is a auto generated  content.

Comment: The long and the short is that Google sees these sites as low quality mostly comprised of data driven content that generally does not distinguish itself with value add. I should know. I had a similar site for systems that were compromised and hacking into other systems or sending spam. Google is penalizing these sites unless you have an incredible amount of links and have been recognized as a golden child such as domaintools.com which is not better than most. You are not going to get traction without a huge high quality link profile. Sorry.

Comment: These sites were pingedby by Panda a couple of years ago. Not all of them, but almost all of them.